# Swap div background if above certain window size

Tags: jquery, html, css, dynamic, size

I have a big banner (div with a background) on my website. I want that people with bigger screens could see it's version in higher resolution.
How can I do it? Do I need JQuery for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved using CSS3 Media Queries. The way a media query works is that you can set different CSS for different screen sizes.

In your HTML you have the DIV and that is it for the HTML:

```
<div id="banner"></div>
```

Your CSS would look a little like this:

```
#banner{
  background-image:url('image_low_res.jpg');
}

@media (min-width: 600px){
  #banner{
    background-image:url('image_med_res.jpg');
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1000px){
  #banner{
    background-image:url('image_high_res.jpg');
  }
}
```

The first lines set for screens 600px and smaller. The middle sets the CSS for screens 600px-1000px and the last lines are for anything 1000px+.

Here is a nice tutorial for CSS3 Media Queries: http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Answer (score 0):

You could use jquery for this, or go with Media queries for a plan CSS Solution. With Media queries you can Check for window, device width and many more.

You could try:

`@media Screen (min-width:500px) { Background-image:url(x2.jpg) }`